# Programmatically generate and share rich proposal documents

Tags: rest, pdf-generation

I would like to programmatically create price proposals from one of our web applications, preferably via a REST API. We would like to be able to share the proposal as either a web page or a PDF and send via email. The proposal should include images, text, price table and video.

It is essential that we are notified when the user receives/opens the proposal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Invoice Ninja](https://docs.invoiceninja.com/proposals.html) has such options for proposals as I understand although personally I have not used the proposals function myself.. I can however wholeheartedly recommend the application as we have been using it for well over 3 years as a self hosted solution for our needs... It is an [open source project](https://github.com/invoiceninja/invoiceninja) which you can self-host or use their [SaaS offering](https://www.invoiceninja.com/invoicing-pricing-plans/) which also has a free tier..

We also use the database created by the application for customised reporting through other software.

Hope this helps.